# XML Parsing, weird behavior.(Works for first 3 dates, rest remains blank)

Tags: c#, xml

So this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string Xml;
        Xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText (@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Practice Projects\C#\XML.txt");
        //Console.WriteLine(Xml);
        string created = Xml.Substring(Xml.IndexOf("<created>")+30,15);
        string modified = Xml.Substring(Xml.IndexOf("<modified>") + 31, 15);
        string revised = Xml.Substring(Xml.IndexOf("<revised>") + 30, 15);
        string lastAccessed = Xml.Substring(Xml.IndexOf("<lastaccessed>") + 35, 15);
        Console.WriteLine (lastAccessed);
        string updatedBy = Xml.Substring(Xml.IndexOf("<updatedby>") + 17, 9);
        Console.WriteLine (updatedBy);
        string mailBody = Xml.Substring(Xml.IndexOf(""));
        //string status;

        Mail mail = new Mail();
        mail.Created = DateTime.ParseExact (created, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine ("The e-Mail was created on: " + mail.Created);
        mail.Modified   = DateTime.ParseExact (modified,"yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine ("The e-MAil was last modified on: " + mail.Modified);
        mail.Revised = DateTime.ParseExact (revised, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine ("The e-Mail was revised on: " + mail.Revised);
        mail.LastAccessed = DateTime.ParseExact (lastAccessed, "yyyyMMddTHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine ("The e-Mail was last accessed on:", mail.LastAccessed);
        mail.UpdatedBy = updatedBy;
        Console.WriteLine ("The e-Mail was last updated by: ", mail.UpdatedBy);
        mail.MailBody = mailBody;
        Console.WriteLine ("The e-Mail body is: ", mail.MailBody);
Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static string PraseDateTime (string Text, string StartTag, string EndTag)
    {
        int StartPosition = Text.IndexOf(StartTag) + StartTag.Length;
        int Length = Text.IndexOf(EndTag) - StartPosition;
        return Text.Substring(StartPosition, Length - 6);
    }

public class Mail
{
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    public DateTime Revised { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public Requester Caller { get; set; }
    public String MailBody { get; set; }

    public Mail ()
    {
        Caller = new Requester();
    }
}
```

So the problem is that my code works for the first 3, but it shows nothing when it comes to the last 2: lastAccessed and updatedBy, the text remains blank even tho when i check to see this 2 variables they clearly contain something. (first contains the date like: 20120522T230123 and the second (name) like: WGAMaster) I can add that the lastAccessed is the same as modified, yet for lastAccessed doesn't work.

I would appreciate any kind of help, or a better way to parse the text from an XML. Thank you!

Comment: First of all, this isn't a proper way of parsing xml documents. use `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` class.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using XML. Why don't you use proper Xml Parser. .NET provides classes to parse an XML file for example you can use XmlDocument class or XmlSerializer. You can look at an example using XmlSerializer @https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I will look into the XMLSerializer, tho for now it looks alien to me. I am still unsure if that method is good for what i am trying to do, but i will give it a try.